# What values does window.open use to determine whether to open a new tab or go to a pre-existing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am in the process of opening new tabs and accessing existing tabs and I am trying to figure out why sometimes a new tab is opened and sometimes the browser says 'Hey a tab with that name is already open, let me just reopen that same tab.'

Can someone tell me what these exact params are that it is looking at.

Is it just the title, is it a combo of the url and title? Or is it something else?

Comment: The second argument of `open` is the name you're looking for, it is not a title.

Comment: Ok, do you know if that is all it looks at in the scenario where on a button click on another page does a window.open() with the same title. Should the browser open another tab or find the existing tab with the same title?

Comment: Has nothing to do with title.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I'd say it should find an existing tab/pop-up with the same name. If you always want a new tab/window, use `_blank` as the name.

Comment: @Teemu Would it be safe to say that you can only navigate back to tabs that were previously opened by a window.open? It seems like I can never get back to my original tab if I wanted to.

Comment: Navigate how? That maybe an other question anyway.

Comment: @Teemu The pattern that I am starting to notice is that lets say I have a Parent page with a button click that does a window.open('Page2', 'xyz'). Then Page2 has a button click that does a window.open('Page3', 'abc'). Then finally Page3 has a button called Back to Page2 which does window.open('Page2', 'xyz'). This would easily go back to Page2, but I don't think there is a way to ever get back to the initial Parent page since it was never opened with a window.open. Make sense?

Comment: On the main page, give a name to window, ex. `window.name = 'main'`, and use that name in the other tabs.

Comment: @Teemu You may have just saved me major headache. I am going to try this. Do I just do it at the top of the page in js tags?

Comment: Yep, that makes sure the name exists when it is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147648/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-teemu).

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of window.open dictates this. Opening a window with a new name should cause a new tab to open instead of replacing an old tab.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Would it be safe to say that you can only navigate back to tabs that were previously opened by a window.open? It seems like I can never get back to my original tab if I wanted to.